# Unexpected shutdown in cassandra due to outofmemory error

Tags: java, cassandra, out-of-memory, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using cassandra 2.0.9, in which i got some unexpected shutdown says OutOfMemoryError, While minor compaction running background i got this error. before that i had some warning about tombstones. but i have set gc_grace as one day only.

```
WARN [ReadStage:95] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,548 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 225) Read 1 live and 21072 tombstoned cells in mykeyspace.user_metrics_overview (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 1 columns was requested, slices=[-], delInfo={deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=2147483647}
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:68695] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,550 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:68695,1,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306)
        at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:174)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:195)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:149)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.decompressChunk(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.reBuffer(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedThrottledReader.reBuffer(CompressedThrottledReader.java:41)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.seek(RandomAccessReader.java:280)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(SSTableScanner.java:203)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner.hasNext(SSTableScanner.java:183)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:144)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.<init>(MergeIterator.java:87)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator.get(MergeIterator.java:46)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionIterable.iterator(CompactionIterable.java:47)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runWith(CompactionTask.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionTask.run(CompactionManager.java:198)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,551 ThriftServer.java (line 141) Stop listening to thrift clients
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:68695] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,551 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:68695,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:705)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon$2.uncaughtException(CassandraDaemon.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.handleOrLog(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:220)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$CompactionExecutor.afterExecute(CompactionManager.java:973)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,590 Server.java (line 182) Stop listening for CQL clients
 INFO [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-03-09 06:10:31,590 Gossiper.java (line 1279) Announcing shutdown
```

Anyone help me. When I read data using hector 1.0-5, this error won't occured. But while reading data using datastax java-driver core 2.0.5, this error occurred. Is there any problem with that driver? Is there any difference in reading data using thrift and cql? My keyspace is an old one, created using cassandra-cli, it's schema is

```
create column family user_metrics_overview
with column_type = 'Standard' 
and comparator = 'ReversedType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType)' 
and default_validation_class = 'BytesType' 
and key_validation_class = 'BytesType'
```

Comment: JVM is not able to allocate the direct buffer, you may want to increase it and try most probably that might solve as well. for ex: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256/512m default, I believe, is 64m.

Comment: I have not set  -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize parameter. What will be the default value, if not set any value? @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu

Comment: I believe it is JVM dependent but for Sun/Oracle JVM default is 64 MB .

Comment: How much memory is on this node? I don't think tombstones are your main problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Memory Analyzer to see what is eating up memory.Check heapdump to analyze the cause for eating up space.